# Web Service Complex Type Read Only Property

Tags: c#, web-services, interface

I want to have a WCF web service that use complex type for interface.

```
bool SetFunction(MyComplexType data);

MyComplexType GetFunction(int compextDataId);

public class MyComplexType
{
    public string LabelNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InsertDate { get; set; }
}
```

I do not want my clients to set all properties of MyComplexType but could read some of them.

When I deploy those functions , wsdl is generated with all of the properties of MyComplexType and I do not want clients to set some specific values( InsertDate ) When they use GetComplexType they should read those values because they need it.

I tried to play with { get; set; } to generate specific interface but i have to use those in server side.

How I could hide some class properties from web service interface with using same class?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF then using data contracts should solve your problem.

Following is the example code of decorating MyComplexType with [DataContract] attribute. Note that when you don't mark any public property with Datamember ,it won't appear in WSDL.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyComplexType
{
    public string TestStringNotVisible { get; set; } //this won't be displayed

    [DataMember]
    public bool TestBoolVisibleInWsdl { get; set; } = true;

    [DataMember]
    public string TestStringVisibleInWsdl { get; set; } = "Hello ";
}
```

Comment: I want some members to appear only on Get functions. using [DataMember]   hide set and get function all together.